# AirDrop version for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, file-sharing, iphone

Any way to use AirDrop type of snap app for Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 5):

As explained at [here](https://iphone-tricks.com/tutorial/3064-airdrop-for-windows-android-and-linux-snapdrop) you can install [SnapDrop](https://onedoes.github.io/snapdrop/) (also on [snapdrop.net](https://snapdrop.net/)) for Linux and gain similar functionality in your browser. Here's its [Readme](https://github.com/RobinLinus/snapdrop) on GitHub and its [FAQ](https://github.com/RobinLinus/snapdrop#frequently-asked-questions).

Comment: Does this work as fast as of Airdrop, like the on on Mac?

Answer (score 2):

I actually just use Slack.  Slack DM to myself on my phone w/ the attachment I want to send.  Grab the file using Slack for Linux.

It's not airdrop - but it does quickly transfer files, photos, etc from my phone to my ubuntu laptop.